# Schedule Python Selenium to run daily using Batch .bat

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, batch-file, selenium-chromedriver

I create a batch file to run Python Selenium, but the browser does not open, but with an error msg

```
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

my .bat script:

```
"C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\tom\Downloads\selenium.py"
pause
```

my python code in Jupyter notebook is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

time.sleep(3)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(1)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.set_page_load_timeout('10')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is ChromeDriver in your PATH? I have had a similar error and was able to resolve it by adding that to my path as the error suggests.

If you don't want to add it to your PATH you should be able to just specify the exact executable location. This should work for you if you replace the path with the correct one.

webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\folder\path\to\chromedriver.exe')

Comment: You're the man, it works. and make sure to use the straight python 3.7, not sure why 3.6 will raise other issues. Don't use the Anaconda's pythonw.exe, it will fail too. \anaconda3\pythonw.exe